# How to get Current Date date in PST format?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I need current date string . I have already tried searching . What we get currently from

```
    [NSDate currentDate];
```

is in UTC. Either tell me how to convert it in PST or directly get current date in PST.

Comment: `currentDate` is not in UTC, it's a point of time, it has no time zone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];

NSDateFormatter *formatterUTC = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatterUTC.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"];
[formatterUTC setDateFormat:@"MMM dd,yyyy, hh:mm a"];
NSString *dateString = [formatterUTC stringFromDate:date];

NSDate *dateFromString1 = [formatterUTC dateFromString:dateString];
NSDateFormatter *formatterPST = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatterPST setDateFormat:@"MMM dd,yyyy, hh:mm a"];

formatterPST.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"America/Los_Angeles"];

NSString *urdate = [formatterPST stringFromDate:dateFromString1];`
```

Comment: I don't understand the explanation. Where is the conversion to UTC?

Answer (score 2):

In case someone is looking for a solution in swift:

```
public func getCurrentDateIn(timeZone: String) -> Date? {

// get a dateFormatter
let dateFormatter              = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat       = "MMM dd,yyyy, hh:mm a"
let currentDateString : String = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())

// get currentDate in string format
guard let currentDate          = dateFormatter.date(from: currentDateString) else { return nil }

// change the timezone of dateFormatter to timeZone
dateFormatter.timeZone         = TimeZone.init(abbreviation: timeZone)

// get current date in timeZone in string format from dateFormatter
let timeZoneDateString         = dateFormatter.string(from: currentDate)

// change the timeZone of dateFormatter to current otherwise it will apply conversion again.
dateFormatter.timeZone         = TimeZone.current
return dateFormatter.date(from: timeZoneDateString)
```

}

//Test Cases

getCurrentDateIn(timeZone: "IST")
"Apr 14, 2019 at 12:11 AM"

getCurrentDateIn(timeZone: "PST")
"Apr 13, 2019 at 11:41 AM"

getCurrentDateIn(timeZone: "SGT")
"Apr 14, 2019 at 2:41 AM"